# yo cannot find jhipster after yarn global add generator-jhipster

Tags: node.js, jhipster, yo, yarnpkg

I'm trying to generate a jHipster project using yarn - https://jhipster.github.io/installation/

I installed Node from its website and yarn with brew.

yarn version 0.19.1
node version v7.5.0
OSX Sierra 10.12.3

When I run `yarn global add generator-jhipster`, I could see jhispter generator being copied to /Users/{username}/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/

```
my-mac:~ user$ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v0.19.1
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
warning undefined has no binaries
warning No license field
✨  Done in 30.68s.
```

As the next step, when I run `yo jhipster`, it cannot find jhipster. However, when I run `yarn add generator-jhipster`, yo can find jhipster from current folder. Not sure whats wrong with adding in global location.

```
my-mac:~ user$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.5.0/bin:/Users/{user}/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
```

Will appreciate any help in identify whats going on or if there is any issue with latest yarn version.

```
my-mac:~ user$ yo jhipster
Error jhipster

You don’t seem to have a generator with the name “jhipster” installed.
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and the cause was my laziness. I did not took time to read the notes of Local installation with Yarn documentation:

Note: if you have problem to use these tools globally, be sure you have $HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin in your path.

On Mac or Linux: `export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin):$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin"`

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue I needed to install yeoman globally with yarn.

```
yarn global add yo
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu and I faced this issue too. Then I use `sudo` to add yo package

`sudo yarn global add yo`

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: Can someone explain me why this is wrong? It was worked for me. and with the experience of npm, we used to use 'sudo' to installing global packages. thats why I use same with yarn